# Sharekit testflight and pods

Tags: ios, sharekit, cocoapods

I have a sharekit installed with cocoa pods , when I run using xcode and build on my iPhone sharekit works, but when I archive and put to testflight sharekit doesn't work.
What can cause the problem??

Comment: Define "doesn't work'

Comment: noting happens when click but no errors or crash

Comment: I have the same archive problem with sharekit.bundle, it says "rsync error: some files could not be transferred..." and "ShareKit.bundle" failed: No such file or directory". I'm not sure if it's a Cocoapods' problem or Sharekit's. Have you figured out how to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as in my application would build and run on the simulator, but the `.ipa` was rejected by the Appstore. Apparently my archive was rejected due to '*Unsupported Architectures*'.

What solved my issue was the following:

- Added all ShareKit `.bundle` dependencies as separate pods.

e.g.

`pod 'LiveSDK'
 pod 'google-plus-ios-sdk'`

- Followed [this article](http://ikennd.ac/blog/2015/02/stripping-unwanted-architectures-from-dynamic-libraries-in-xcode/) by Daniel Kennett to remove unwanted architectures.

Hope this helps.